# Tuning deep models with dataset subsample

Tags: model-selection, deep-learning, large-data, hyperparameter

I have a quite big dataset (380k samples), and I am try to do model selection over my validation set (3K samples). Since to run a single model requires days, I have subsample my training set (taking 10k samples) and use it to find the best model (the one with the lowest).

Now the questions are:

- Is this a good practice?
- Is this process going to select a model that underfit?
- Is there any other way to run a model selection in a large dataset?